# JavaSpaces tutorials

Tags: java, javaspaces

Where could I find JavaSpaces tutorials?

Points of interests for me:

- What can I do with it?
- How do I use it?
- How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what cs94njw mentioned, I would also recommend [JavaSpaces](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/dist/appc_01.htm) as well as [The Nature Of JavaSpaces](http://www.dancres.org/cottage/javaspaces.html).

Answer (score 1):

Quick google search:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/tools/JavaSpaces/
http://www.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/XAP7/Plain+JavaSpaces+Tutorial